# Scala: How to use case keyword without match keyword?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I wrote a section code for testing:

```
class A extends JavaTokenParsers {
    def str: Parser[Any] = stringLiteral ~ ":" ~ stringLiteral ^^ 
                    { case x ~ ":" ~ y => (x, y) }    //how to use case keyword like this?
}

object B extends A with App{
    val s = """
            "name": "John"
            """
    println(parseAll(str, s))
}
```

I read "Chapter 15: Case Classes and Pattern Matching" of ***Programming in Scala Second Edition*** , but I never saw **case** used like this:

```
... ^^ { case x ~ ":" ~ y => (x, y) }
```

It's not **match** keyword, but ^^ looks like **match**. I know **partial functions** and I can use **case** by this way:

```
object C extends App {
    def a(f: Int => Int) = {
        f(3)
    }
    a(x => x + 1)
    a { case x => x + 1 }
}
```

But they are all different:

1. **^^** function like **match**, which can use content before **^^** matching  content behind **case**
2. **case** in ^^ function can use function(like **~**)

How to write custom function like ^^? Can you write a concrete example? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just syntactic sugar. In scala, you can use any method that takes a single parameter as a binary operator.

Example:

```
class Foo(x: String) {
  def ^^(pf: PartialFunction[String, Int]): Option[Int] =
    if (pf.isDefinedAt(x)) Some(pf(x)) else None
}

val foo = new Foo("bar")
foo ^^ {
  case "baz" => 41
  case "bar" => 42
}

// result: Some(42)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But it looks very simple. I want **case** expression can contain variables(like **x,y** above) and function(like **~** above). Thanks again!

Comment: that's an entirely different matter. You can define a custom `unapply` and define the behavior of the extractor. Look up "extractors" and you'll find a lot of information about it.

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned, you can use a block with the case keyword to create a partial function.

```
val doubleIntGtThree: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
  case x: Int if x > 3 => x * 2
}
doubleIntGtThree(4) // return 8
doubleIntGtThree(2) //throws a matchError
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But Partial function is not what I need for my question. They are different.

Comment: Ok, sorry I didnt fully understand what you wanted to achieve.